# UE4 | Glitch with movable cube

Tags: unreal-4

I've been trying to make something so that when you press a button, a cube appears. Problem is, whenever I jump on said cube, it sends me flying away so far my character gets deleted (not a game mechanic). I have noted that this problem only arises when the object mode is in movable, this does not happen when it is static. (I am using AddActorWorldOffset, so it is necessary). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to UE4 space program ;) , is the cube moving when the character jumps on it ? Consider disabling physics for the character, characters movement component should be able to handle gravity, and should be able to land on a cube. Perhaps you will also want to decrease sub-stepping time amount and increase substepping iterations amount.

Comment: @ColdSteel No, the cube has already ceased moving by the time you can jump on it. I'll try disabling physics though!